# Python using dict of "triggers strings" lists to output a new labeled dict from a list of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have pre-defined a dict of list of string triggers:

```
triggers = {'academic': ['studied at', 'studies at', 'studies', 'studies at'],
     'age': ['years old','months old'],
     'gender': ['male', 'female'],
     'pets': ['dog','cat'],
     'location': ['Lived in','Lives in']}
```

and I have a not previously known list of lists of grouped information data, example:

```
example_list_of_list = [['Former Teacher of math at'],
 ['Studies programming at', 'Stackoverflow'],
 ['Lives in','Chicago'],
 ['owns','dog', 'cat']
```

I want to append each matching list element to a new dictionary using the match pre-defined key value, such as:

```
{'academic': ['Former Teacher of math at'],
'age': None, # np.nan or []
'gender': None, # np.nan or []
'pets': ['owns','dog','cat']
'location': ['Lives in','Chicago']
 }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using set semantics most easily, I think:

```
result = {}
for input in example_list_of_list:
    for key, triggerset in triggers.items():
        if not input.isdisjoint(triggerset):
            result[key] = result.get(key,[]).append(input)
```

Though note a couple things:

- `triggers` should be a `dict` of `set`s not `list`s.
- `example_list_of_lists` should be a `list` of `set`s instead
- `result` is a `dict` of `list`s of `list`s because more than one input might match

Comment: `len(triggers.values()),len(triggers.keys())` is (10,10) and input is length 4 (four sets). but I'm still getting `ValueError: too many values to unpack` when I try `for key, triggerset in triggers:`

Comment: oops! forgot to call `.items()`. Edited.

Comment: The odd thing is that this actually works for the example data I gave, but for the actual data I have, it's returning an empty `dict`, so it's not working since I know exactly which elements should match. I'm too sleepy right now, but I'm definitely checking out a fix later! Thanks!